# Progress bar not showing unless in shift key bypass mode

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database that does not display the database window when opening.  Instead it displays a switchboard.  I do have some queries and reports that take awhile to run and want to display the progress bar to the user.  The only way I can get the progress bar to display is when I enter the database using the shift key bypass to bring up the database window.  Then, the progress bar displays and works great.  How do I get it to show when the database window is not showing?

I use the following to initialize the progress bar:

```
Application.SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "Progress:", 500
```

Then inside of a loop I use the following to update the progress bar:

```
TempRecordCount = TempRecordCount + 1
Application.SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, TempRecordCount
```

Then once it is no longer needed I perform the following:

```
Application.SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Tools --> Startup... --> [x] Display Status Bar**

I suspect that when you unchecked the box next to "Display Database Window" in the Startup options, you also unchecked the box next to "Display Status Bar".  Since the progress meter is displayed in the Status Bar, you need to make sure that option is checked.

Comment: Hey, that is exactly what I did.  I can't believe I didn't notice that.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sometimes all you need is a second set of eyes.